# is a way to see all data in tooltip when the points are overlap with each other(or very close), but see only one data when a point is far from others

Tags: highcharts

For line chart tooltip, if we set "share: true", we can see all data with same X-Axis value in a single bubble. if we set "share: false", we can see only one data in single bubble.

My question is whether there is a way to see all data in tooltip when the points are overlap with each other(or very close), but see only one data when a point is far from others.

Comment: Something like this is not supported. You can create an idea [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general).

Comment: added this as an idea for highcharts https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/40394740-tooltip-option-to-only-show-overlapping-series-in