# HighCharts: Use shared tooltip only when series overlap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the below `HighCharts` example, the series `A` and `B` have identical data. Only the line for `B` is visible in the chart plot area, as it is plotted directly over `A`.

It is impossible for the end user to know that the `A` is behind `B`.

We can set `tooltip.shared = true` in the configuration object to show all the data values for a given x-axis point when hovered over any series.  However, in my real-life example I have up to 50 series plotted on the chart and this is not appropriate.

Is it possible to keep the behaviour of `tooltip.shared = false`, but when the user hovers over a series that overlaps at that point with one or more series, to show all (and only) of the overlapping series values in the tooltip? Or is there any other user-friendly way to indicate that there are 2+ identical y-values at a given x-value?

http://jsfiddle.net/adamtsiopani/XbYZz/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adamtsiopani/XbYZz/

Comment: Suggested this as a feature to highcharts. Give your votes there: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/40394740-tooltip-option-to-only-show-overlapping-series-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Highcharts doesn't have a solution for this yet. They have a feature to hide one series so other is visible, this is a good alternative. But if you need to get a shared tool-tip when the 2 series overlap it can be done as shown in the below fiddle.

```
$(function () {
    var series1 = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];

    var series2 = [24.9, 50.5, 106.4, 90.2, 80.0, 150.0, 160.6, 170.5, 160.4, 180.1, 95.6, 54.4];

    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                var s1 = this.series.chart.series[0].processedYData[this.point.index];
                var s2 = this.series.chart.series[1].processedYData[this.point.index];
                if (s1 == s2) {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.chart.series[0].name + ' :' + s1 + '</b><br/><b>' + this.series.chart.series[1].name + ' :' + s2 + '</b><br/>in month : ' + this.x;
                }
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ' :' + this.y + '</b><br/>in month : ' + this.x;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: series1
        }, {
            data: series2
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Malinga/2jbdqe6x/7/

reference:http://www.malinga.me/highcharts-shared-tooltips-only-in-overlapping-points/#more-109

Comment: Very nice! Here is an updated example with dynamic chart sizing which measures the distance in pixels: http://jsfiddle.net/2jbdqe6x/9/

Comment: Malinga,  thanks for you input on this. I've changed the Correct answer to yours. I like @Sphinxxx input also, perhaps you could update the answer to show his as an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

Unless an elaborate work-around is concocted, highcharts does not support this yet.  See this post (which has a comment from a user who claims to be a highcharts engineer):

> [is a way to see all data in tooltip when the points are overlap with each other(or very close), but see only one data when a point is far from others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366916/is-a-way-to-see-all-data-in-tooltip-when-the-points-are-overlap-with-each-other)

I guess you will just have to rely on users using the legend for deselecting a series that is blocking another one.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Relying on users using the legend is also not ideal due to the amount of series I am displaying. I had to disable the ability for users to hide/show a series by the legend as it suffers major performance problems with a large number of series. I'm hoping to stumble upon "an elaborate work-around" !

Comment: @PawełFus haha, I thought I voted your comment on the original post, but just had to.

Answer (score 0):

As user, I would be confused to see 50 series on a chart - is that readable?  Good idea would be to use separate yAxis, or separate panes, but still 50 series..

However, you can do some workaround. Don't use shared tooltip, but in tooltip formatter, get actual x-index (for example `var xIndex = series.xData.indexOf(this.x);`) then loop through all series, get values from series data (for example `var yValue = series.yData[xIndex];`). Now compare with `this.y` and if values are similar add more points to the returned tooltip.

Comment: I will try to implement this solution and if I get it working I will post a jsFiddle update and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: regarding your comments on "separate yAxis or separate planes" can you post a working jsFiddle example? The chart looks confusing, however, the main use case for these charts if for the user to identify only the top few series in terms of y-value. In our system these are "problem series". They then hover the line to see what series it is and click on the line to drilldown to related data.

Comment: I mean something like this: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

Comment: I tried to play around with this kind of solution, but to no avail. It seemed like unless the tooltip was shared, you could not access other value points from inside the formatter.  Maybe you can call an outside function to help out?

Comment: I'm struggling with this for the exact reason in @Sualkcin comment. Is there another approach?